Transfer a domain from namecheap to cloudflare
So I have a .com domain deployed on digitalocean with https - certbot. After i make the transfer do I need to change anything https wise? I see cloudflare has its own https process which needs some sort of key etc. Thanks for your time.

Yes, after transferring to Cloudflare, you'll need to update your SSL settings. Cloudflare provides SSL certificates, but ensure your SSL mode is set to Full or Full (strict) for HTTPS to work with your existing Certbot configuration.
